# How to resample a time series Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, ipython

I am trying to resample 1 minute based data to day. I have tried the following code on IPython

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, Panel
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv("DATALOG_22_01_2014.csv",\
names = ['DATE','TIME','HUM1','TMP1','HUM2','TMP2','HUM3','TMP3','WS','WD'])

data.set_index(['DATE','TIME'])

data.resample('D',how=mean)
```

But I got the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-75-aa63b6b16877> in <module>()
----> 1 data.resample('D', how=mean)

NameError: name 'mean' is not defined
```

Could you help me?

Thank you

Hugo

Comment: use ``data.set_index(['DATE','TIME'],inplace=True``; the returned copy now is just getting discarded so the resample will fail

Comment: Thank you!!! It works. So it "dropped" the index column?

Comment: no, ``set_index`` returns a new frame (the inplace modifies data on the other hand). most pandas functions return a new object, usually you would do ``data = data.set_index(['DATE','TIME']) ; resampled_data = data.resample('D',how='mean')``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
data.resample('D', how='mean')
```

instead.  Right now you're asking Python to pass the `mean` object to the `resample` method as the `how` argument, but you don't have one defined.

Comment: Thank you. I got a new error. Bu it's too long to fit here. How can I send it to you?

Comment: @Hugo: SO works in a question/answer format, where you ask discrete, specific questions and then those are answered, rather than a threaded format in which you ask multiple questions.  [Aside: you're also probably going to have to use `parse_dates`, and `set_index` doesn't work in place.  I recommend reading through the tutorial.]

Comment: OK. I will. Thank you once again